# Two videos side-by-side on one beamer slide using \movie and \usepackage{multimedia}?

Tags: beamer, video

Is it possible to only use \movie and the \usepackage{multimedia} to place two movies on a single beamer slide and to play them at the same time. I spent a day trying to install media9 and while to movies play their quality is far inferior to the I use \movie and \usepackage{multimedia}.

Thanks,

Istvan.

Comment: Cannot believe the quality issue. How did you produce the MP4? Usually MP4+H264 is far superior than anything. In A-Reader, simultaneous, side by side playback is only possible with the media9 embedding method.

Comment: Quick time player on a mac. The video looks ok on my mac when watching it but it is very pixelated in the resulting compiled pdf.

Comment: Did you produce the video from a set of image files (e. g. PNG) or by converting from a different video format?

Comment: It was a screen recording. I have a java application that produces a video on screen and I recorded this using Quick Time player's Screen Record functionality.

Comment: Thus you are recording (using QuickTime) an already playing video? This may not be  the optimal workflow. Can you instruct the Java app to output the video into a file directly? Btw, for \movie (multimedia) you will have to further convert the video to AVI or MOV. I doubt you will get a better result.